# C Warning when comparing strings

Tags: c

I have the following code to check if the process path has the value iexplore.exe:

```
void GetDataElement(WCHAR process_name[MAX_PATH]){

CHAR *IEName = "iexplore.exe";
...

GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess,NULL,process_name,MAX_PATH)

...

if(strstr(process_name,IEName)!=NULL){
   ...
}
```

However, I am getting the following warning:

> 'function': incompatible types - from 'WCHAR *' to 'const char *'

I do not know how to convert my variable `process_name` into const char *, in order to remove that warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert const WCHAR \* to const char \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637779/how-to-convert-const-wchar-to-const-char)

Comment: i would suggest casting to a const char, not sure how to do that speifically because i dont know the data structure you are using for that "WCHAR".

Comment: @RandomDavis Tks for your help. I saw that post but I do not have a const WCHAR* but WCHAR. That is why I am asking how to do it?

Comment: Maybe duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637779/how-to-convert-const-wchar-to-const-char

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637779/how-to-convert-const-wchar-to-const-char/22862005

Comment: Why don't you make `IEName` a `WCHAR *` and use [`wcsstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l?view=msvc-160) instead of `strstr`?