# Converting wchar_t * to char * in C++20

Tags: c++, char, wchar-t

Currently using WSL2 Ubuntu, G++20.

What are some recommended ways to convert wchar_t * to char * in C++20? I have seen similar posts created several years ago, but I wasn't sure if they were still viable as a solution or if they were deprecated.

Comment: What encoding do your wide strings have, and what encoding do you want in your byte strings?

Comment: wide strings have UTF-16, the encoding I want in my byte strings is UTF-8

Comment: What are the "solutions" you have seen? What have you tried yourself? What problems (if any) do you have with your attempt?

Comment: Mainly from these two pages: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637779/how-to-convert-const-wchar-to-const-char/44375695> and <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=msvc-160>.

I've tried using sprintf, which causes a buffer overflow.
I've tried using _bstr_t, but I can't seem to get <comdef.h> to work.
I've heard about <codecvt> but apparently some functionality has been deprecated since C++17.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [wcstombs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs) (and [wcsrtombs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs)) is still relevant in C++ 20:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>
 
int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    // UTF-8 narrow multibyte encoding
    const wchar_t* wstr = L"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001d10b"; // or L"zß水"
    char mbstr[11];
    std::wcstombs(mbstr, wstr, 11);
    std::cout << "multibyte string: " << mbstr << '\n';
}
```

Comment: How do I determine what the size of the char buffer has to be?

Comment: If `dst` is `nullptr`, the number of characters required to convert the wide-character string is returned.

Comment: @alex_noname It's a POSIX extension of the standard. Fortunately the MSVC implementation works the same, but care should still be taken if true portability is needed.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the number of characters required or is this the only way?

Comment: I don’t know of any other convenient enough way to do this. But you can use [wcsrtombs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs), its behavior when `dst == nullptr` is standardized.